# Getting "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server" when accessing from a specific domain?

Tags: http-status-code-404, sonicwall

We have a simple WP site that has been running for years.  We can access it on mobile or any other computers that are not connected to our company's domain.  I believe there is an error within our firewall.  Any suggestions on where I should look? We use a Dell Sonicwall.

Answer (score 0):

First check the logs, and see if it's being blocked.  Then I would check app control, or the CFS policies.  Probably, the easiest way would be to just put one test machine IP address in a CFS, IPS, or APP Control (or all) bypass group.  Test you can get out to the site.   Once you can access the site, start to re-enable all the security services one by one until you find out what's blocking it.